# CreateWindow() returns nullptr and GetLastError() returns 1400

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Hello I have recently decided to learn graphics programming through DirectX11 and for that I'm learning how to use the Windows API. I managed to create a window by following an online tutorial and later successfully created one by myself. However, the problem starts when I tried to make a framework to create the Window, I ran into a few errors but by studying the documentation and looking up examples most of them were solved, except for one involving the CreateWindow() function.

Whenever I try to get the handle for the window it returns nullptr, I tried getting the error code through GetLastError(), but all I get is 1400, which according to MSDN is "Invalid window handle". I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I haven't found any threads that solved the issue. It compiles successfully, but no window appears.

Window.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include "WindowsHeader.hpp"

class Window
{
public:

    Window(int width, int height, const char* name);
    ~Window();
    Window(const Window&) = delete;
    Window& operator=(const Window&) = delete;

private:

    class WindowClass
    {
    public:

        static const char* GetName() noexcept;
        static HINSTANCE GetInstance() noexcept;

    private:

        WindowClass() noexcept;
        ~WindowClass();
        WindowClass(const WindowClass&) = delete;
        WindowClass& operator=(const WindowClass&) = delete;

        static constexpr const char* window_class_name{ "HardwareAccelerated3D" };
        static WindowClass window_class;
        HINSTANCE hinst;
    };

    static LRESULT CALLBACK HandleMsgSetup(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) noexcept;
    static LRESULT CALLBACK HandleMsgInvoke(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) noexcept;
    LRESULT HandleMsg(HWND, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) noexcept;

    int width;
    int height;
    HWND hwnd;
};
```

Window.cpp

```
#include "Window.hpp"
#include <sstream>

//Window Class

Window::WindowClass Window::WindowClass::window_class;

Window::WindowClass::WindowClass() noexcept
    : hinst(GetModuleHandle(NULL))
{
    WNDCLASSEX window_class{ {0} };
    window_class.cbSize = sizeof(window_class);
    window_class.style = CS_OWNDC;
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = &HandleMsgSetup;
    window_class.cbClsExtra = NULL;
    window_class.cbWndExtra = NULL;
    window_class.hInstance = GetInstance();
    window_class.hIcon = NULL;
    window_class.hCursor = NULL;
    window_class.hbrBackground = NULL;
    window_class.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    window_class.lpszClassName = GetName();
    window_class.hIconSm = NULL;
    RegisterClassEx(&window_class);
}

Window::WindowClass::~WindowClass()
{
    UnregisterClass(GetName(), GetInstance());
}

const char* Window::WindowClass::GetName() noexcept
{
    return window_class_name;
}

HINSTANCE Window::WindowClass::GetInstance() noexcept
{
    return window_class.hinst;
}

//Window

Window::Window(int width, int height, const char* name)
    : width(width), height(height)
{
    RECT wndrec;
    wndrec.left = 100;
    wndrec.right = wndrec.left + width;
    wndrec.top = 100;
    wndrec.bottom = wndrec.top + height;
    if (!AdjustWindowRect(&wndrec, WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU, false))
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << GetLastError();
        OutputDebugString(oss.str().c_str());
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(WindowClass::GetName(), name, WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, wndrec.right - wndrec.left, wndrec.bottom - wndrec.top, NULL,
        NULL, WindowClass::GetInstance(), this);

    if (!hwnd)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << GetLastError();
        OutputDebugString(oss.str().c_str());
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
}

Window::~Window()
{
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
}

LRESULT WINAPI Window::HandleMsgSetup(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) noexcept
{
    if (msg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        const CREATESTRUCTW* const pcreate = reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCTW*>(lparam);
        Window* const pwnd = static_cast<Window*>(pcreate->lpCreateParams);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pwnd));
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(&Window::HandleMsgInvoke));
        return pwnd->HandleMsg(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}

LRESULT WINAPI Window::HandleMsgInvoke(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) noexcept
{
    Window* const pwnd = reinterpret_cast<Window*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
    return pwnd->HandleMsg(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}

LRESULT Window::HandleMsg(HWND, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) noexcept
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}
```

WinMain.cpp

```
#include "WindowsMessageMap.hpp"
#include "Window.hpp"

int CALLBACK WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nShowCmd)
{
    Window window(640, 480, "HardwareAccelerated3D");

    MSG msg;
    BOOL gresult;
    while (gresult = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    if (gresult == -1)
        return -1;
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

WindowsHeader.hpp is just a few defines and Windows.h to avoid some windows macros, and WindowsMessageMap.hpp just prints windows messages to the debug console (I use it to see what messages are being called).

P.S.: this is my first post here, so feel free to point out any issues with the post itself, so that I can be more clear next time.

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: The code uses `Window::hinst` but doesn't seem to initialize it.

Comment: The `WindowClass` constructor is initializing and registering a local `WNDCLASSEX` variable named `window_class`, shadowing the static `WindowClass::window_class` member.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried renaming the function member as `m_wndclass` so that they don't share the same name, but I'm still getting the same problem. Is there a problem with the constructor's logic?

Comment: Hi,if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `hwnd` you used in the code is the same as it in `Window.hpp`:

```
LRESULT Window::HandleMsg(HWND, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) noexcept
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}
```

The last line of Window.hpp:

```
HWND hwnd;
```

When you call `HandleMsg`, `hwnd` of `Window.hpp` is not initialized:

[image]

You may use `hwnd` in `HandleMsgSetup`, just add the `hwnd` param like the following code:

```
LRESULT Window::HandleMsg(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) noexcept
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}
```

And it works for me:

[image]